# Does this "custom react hook" breaks the hooks law?

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I am using many useCallbacks in useEffects in the same format syntax and feel like shortening them. So, I map them in this hook. `effects` is an array of useCallback functions.

```
import React from 'react';
    const useEffects = (effects: Function[]) =>
      effects.map((effect) =>
        React.useEffect(() => {
          effect();
        }, [effect])
      );
export default useEffects;
```

Comment: Yes, you can't `useEffect` inside a callback

Comment: React hooks should be called at the top-most scope of a component, please check https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: i believe you can't use hooks inside an array. Because we don't know the length of the array. And all hooks are registered based on their physical location order.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can't be defined inside an array.

I wrote an article recently about the rendering order of hooks. https://windmaomao.medium.com/understanding-hooks-part-4-hook-c7a8c7185f4e

It really goes down to below snippet how Hooks is defined.

```
function hook(Hook, ...args) {
  let id = notify()
  let hook = hooks.get(id)
  if(!hook) {
    hook = new Hook(id, element, ...args)
    hooks.set(id, hook)
  }
  return hook.update(...args)
}
```

When a hook is registered, it requires an unique id, as in line `notify()`. Which is just a plain `i++` placed inside the Component where the hook is written inside.

So if you have a fixed physical location of the hook, you have a fixed `id`. Otherwise the `id` can be random, and since the render `Component` function is called every render cycle, a random `id` is not going to find the right hook in the next render cycle.

That is why `if` can not be written before the hook statement either. Just try

```
  const Component = () => {
    const b = true
    if (!b) return null
    const [a] = useState(1)
  }
```

You should get similar error.